# Java cannot find symbol becker.robots in JCreator

Tags: java, jcreator

So I have made a class and another but when I try to compile it cannot find the symbol. I am using JCreator but I am not sure why the first class wont use the second class. Ive had this problem before please help.
Here is my code:

*class I made

```
import becker.robots.*;


public class SpiderBot extends RobotSE
{


//SpiderBot class is created.
public SpiderBot(City aCity, int aStr, int anAve, Direction aDir)
{ super(aCity, aStr, anAve, aDir);
}

//Method to climb building.
public void climbBuilding()
{ this.turnLeft();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.turnRight();
  this.move();
}

//Method to climb down building.
public void climbDownBuilding()
{ this.move();
  this.turnRight();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.move();
  this.turnAround();

}
}

*second class I made that uses the first class.

import becker.robots.*;

public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  //Creating the city and the SpiderBot.
  City NewYork = new City("NewYork.txt");//This is the file that builds the city.
  SpiderBot karel = new SpiderBot(NewYork, 5, 0, Direction.EAST);

  //SpiderBot Climbing the Buildings.
  karel.climbBuilding();
  karel.climbDownBuilding();


    }


}
```

Here are the errors it says:
error: cannot find symbol line 9

Comment: What is the rest of the error? it should point you to something besides the line number.

Comment: ok there is two errors and they both say: error: cannot find symbol  C:Users/Documents/Shane line 11

Comment: What is the symbol you haven't specified the name etc..

Comment: I don't see your line numbering here so how can i tell what you are referring to?

Comment: copy and paste the entire error.

Comment: its on line 11 in the main class where I said: SpiderBot karel = new SpiderBot(.....); and its pointing to the capital S in SpiderBot

Comment: I believe that it is not connecting to the SpiderBot class but I dont know why it isnt that is what I am asking.

Comment: Are both classes in the same directory, are your classes in the same package?

Comment: Im not sure of that so how do I checkÉ

Comment: Im not sure if they are thats my problem I believe.

Comment: actually i think your problem is that you never created a Direction object

Comment: Is East a static field? what does it return, a string?

Comment: Ok so what would I fix? Can you type out the code you think?

Comment: Add the class Direction and I will see. Edit your question by adding class Direction.

Comment: Your on to it I think. It may not be static.

Comment: Post the code and I will see.

Comment: ok just tell me the code to type out in place of which line please

Comment: I dont know where to add the direction class

Comment: Im sorry Im just not sure what you mean

Comment: Click on the edit right below where your question ends, and then modify your question by entering the code. Otherwise I can't help you properly. I need what Direction is.

Comment: But didnt I enter the code? What are you asking by what Direction means? Ok so ill describe what this code is for: I am making a little arrow that moves through a city and what Direction means is the direction the arrow starts in the city like is he facing west, east, north, or south.

Comment: Cant you see the code though?

Comment: i just looked up the api for this, sorry it actually looks fine to me. I'm just wondering why NewYork is highlighted in blue? can you change it to something else?

Comment: what IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: I am using JCreator like i said, I dont know why it doesnt work

Comment: Do you use Linux or Windows?